# asp.net mvc returning view from root

Tags: asp.net-mvc-areas

I have same controller names at two different places in mvc.
One is at the root and the other one is in a Area.
The Index action of the controller in area returns the view from the root.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen. It was because the view was not in the proper path in the area. I had renamed the controller and all links in the calling views, but since the area `area/views/camphome/index.cshtml` was the wrong name, it wasn't picked up, instead it was returning `/views/home/index.cshtml`.

So check if there is no match in the area for the `/controller/action.cshtml`.

I also installed NuGet - `RouteDebugger` so I could spot that the correct controller was being called, just the wrong view was rendering.